# MYSQL Query not able to pull data from Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null, prepare

The problem I'm having is that my Query:

```
SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE nombre_administrador=? AND password=?
```

isn't pulling anything out of the database.

`var_dump` shows:

```
  public 'affected_rows' => null, public 'insert_id' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'param_count' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'errno' => null
  public 'error' => null
  public 'error_list' => null
  public 'sqlstate' => null
  public 'id' => null
```

login.php

```
<?php
    class login{
        //Variable for MySql connection
        private $hookup;
        private $sql;
        private $tableMaster;

        //Field Variables
        private $pass;
        private $name;

        public function __construct()
        {
            //Get table name and make connection
            $this->mysqli=UniversalConnect::doConnect();

            //Get data from HTML form
            $this->name=$_POST['name'];
            $this->pass=$_POST['pass'];
            //Call private methods for MySql operations
            $this->dologin();
            $this->mysqli->close();
        }

        private function dologin()
        {
            if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE nombre_administrador=? AND password=?")){
                var_dump($stmt);
                /* bind parameters for markers */
                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $this->name, $this->pass);
                var_dump($this->name);
                var_dump($this->pass);
                /* execute query */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* bind result variables */
                $stmt->bind_result($id,$nombre_administrador,$password,$ubicacion,$nombre,$apellido);

                /* fetch value */
                $stmt->fetch();
                /*get number of rows*/
                $num_row =$stmt->num_rows;

                if($num_row==1){
                    echo 'true';
                    $_SESSION['Name'] = $row['nombre_administrador'];
                    $_SESSION['Id'] = $row['id'];
                    header("location:  http://localhost/SCAF1.0/indexSCAF.html");
                } else {
                    echo "<script>alert('wrong password');</script>";
                    echo 'false';
                }
            } else{
                echo "Falló la conexión con MySQL: (" . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $this->mysqli->connect_error;
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Umm, your not storing plaintext passwords are you?

Comment: yes, I know the risk and everything but it doesn't take much to change it to md5 once i get it to work

Comment: Have you confirmed that the query result set is not empty?

Comment: yes, acctualy if i var dump the values from post, they give user root and password root, which are in my table, it just seems they're not binding to the query but im not sure why

Answer (score 0):

The backticks shouldn't be a problem but they aren't necessarily needed. It sounds like there might be a connection error.

Comment: I removed the backticks, and still nothing, it doesn't display any query errors either

Comment: Have you checked connection errors? `$this->mysqli->connect_errno` and `$this->mysqli->connect_error`. I would place those right after `$this->mysqli=UniversalConnect::doConnect();`.

Comment: it doesn't show anyeither, actually it was working before, i changed the query and added the prepare portion, it was a plain substitucion in the query before, so im assuming i messed the prepare statement, but i checked the php manual and i can't figure out why wouldn't it work

Comment: and it isn't that ,since it was working when it was just the query with variables, before I changed the code and added prepare

Comment: What does is output of `var_dump($stmt);` right after you prepare the query?

Comment: right after   if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE nombre_administrador=? AND password=?")){ it's all null

Comment: Instead of using `var_dump($stmt);` just inside the IF statement, try this `echo "<pre>" . print_r($stmt, true). "</pre>";`. What does that output?

Comment: mysqli_stmt Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 0
    [insert_id] => 0
    [num_rows] => 0
    [param_count] => 2
    [field_count] => 6
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [id] => 1
)

Comment: Looks like there is something when you do `var_dump($stmt)` that everything is `null` but if you do `print_r($stmt, true);` it actually shows what's in the object. Put that in after `$stmt->bind_param();`, and `$stmt->execute();`. What does it show in those places.

Comment: it doesn't print anything

Comment: It doesn't print anything after which one? Do you have error reporting turned on? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: after any, i placed both lines but it just doesnt do anything, and i just added error reporting, and still nothing

Comment: So before `$stmt->bind_param();` it gave an output. But if you place it after, nothing gets displayed. Try `ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(-1);` to turn on error reporting. What if you place a simple `echo 'Hello';` after `$stmt->bind_param();`?

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. I would step through it line by line and watch what `$stmt` holds. Make sure the value's you're passing for `$this->name` and `$this->pass` actually contain the values you're expecting. It looks alright, I can't step through your code on my local machine.

Comment: i understand thank you, i'll try if not, i might just start over haha